# Hosted website font-awesome Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: css, .htaccess, font-awesome

i have Downloaded the FontAwesome zip from Source Site. 
and included the font-awesome.css file in my Website.

Ealier icons appeared perfectly, Now icons are not coming, showing the below error. may i know the reason for issue.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.traderstree.com/application/views/scripts/templates/clothing-3/includes/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

My Website: [traderstree.com](http://traderstree.com)

Comment: `http://traderstree.com/` != `http://www.traderstree.com/` Your HTML embeds all stylesheets with an absolute URL starting with `http://www.traderstree.com/`, and that _is_ a different domain when you visit your website without the leading `www`. Either make your stylesheet references use relative URLs, or redirect the user from the non-www version to the www-version automatically when they enter your site.

Comment: okay, i have to maintain everytime www.sitename.com whereever i use in my site .?

Comment: If you embed your stylesheets using absolute URLs, then the user has to view the page via the “matching” domain, otherwise you will get this CORS issue with webfonts.

Comment: Thanks alot @CBroe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

And make sure you enabled it with "sudo a2enmod headers" and restart your Apache.

Comment: i can't control the Hosting, any alternative approach thought programming.?

Comment: Do you have FTP access? Then you can create a .htaccess-File in your Root-Directory and fill in the content above.

Comment: Funny how I couldn't figure this... one up